Excel formula dependent on quantities
I'm here for ideas or solutions. I need to create a formula in excel, I am familiar with VBA and power query and know how to do it through them, but here I need to create a formula because this file is used by many people every day and with this formula I will be sure that every time someone saves the file my formula will have the latest value. Because I am working with other software and my code only opens the file and takes the value from cell Z5.
What is my problem, I will explain it with an example. I am part of a large internal process and need to create a report with the month's closing amount. All customers are simple - Quantity * Price = Amount, except one for which I need this formula. This customer has two products A and B and 4 price levels depending on quantity 0-1000, 1001-2000, 2001-3000, 3001+. Product A fills the level first and then Product B.
Example: If product A has 1200 quantities and product B has 910. The distribution will be:




Product A
Product B
Total




Level 1
1000
0
(1000 * PriceA) + (0 * PriceB)


Level 2
200
800
(200 * PriceA) + (800 * PriceB)


Level 3
0
110
(0 * PriceA) + (110 * PriceB)


Level 4
0
0
(0 * PriceA) + (0 * PriceB)




EXAMPLE
I need the Total column in a single cell. I'm trying to do this with a formula that only needs an amount of Product A and Product B.
I tried to do this with lots of ifs... but the end result is one big, big formula.
I would really appreciate it if someone has a better idea than mine

A common approach is to use a lookup table for the prices.

If you can add two more columns, put the price for A and B of each level just next to them; then multiply each column by it's price and sum up on the bottom row.

If I understood it correctly, you're trying to get the values of A and B calculated row wise, where each row (level) it's A & B values together may not exceed 1000.
Also the column values per product may not exceed the input values.
In Office 365 this could be calculated using REDUCE:
=DROP( REDUCE({0,0},SEQUENCE(4),
       LAMBDA(x,level,
LET(A, SUM(INDEX(x,,1)),
    B, SUM(x),
    AB,SUM(E2:F2),
    n, 1000,
    z, IF(A=E2,0,IF(A+n>E2,n-MOD(A+n,E2),n)),
    C, B-z+n,
VSTACK(x,
       HSTACK(z,
              IF(B=AB, 0, IF(C>AB, n-MOD(C,AB), n-z))))))),
      1)


As you can see this spills the result depending on the Input values for total value of Product A in E2 and of Product B in F2.
The formula starts with an initial value, an array of {0,0}; this is the start of x.
Next it starts iterating through the levels (4 in this case). 'level' is declared, but it's only used for iteration purposes.
We then declare A the sum of the values in the first column (product A values) of the last iteration's calculation result of x.
B is the sum of the values for both columns (product A and B values) of the latest iteration's calc result of x.
AB is the total value of the sum of the 2 input values for A and B together.
So for the first column, we calculate if the sum of the previous iteration result for column 1 (A) equals the input value A in E2.
If true it returns 0 for the current calculated row result for product A, else it checks if adding 1000 to A would exceed the input value for A E2. If it doesn't it returns 1000, else the remainder. (this calculation is declared z).
For the second column, we calculate the sum of previous iteration result for both columns (B) equals the sum of both input values (AB).
If it does it returns 0 for the current calculated row result for product B, else it checks if adding 1000 to B minus the current row's calculated value for A (z). This is declared C.
If C exceeds the sum of input values AB, it returns the remainder of 1000 minus C, else it returns 1000.

There is probably a better solution out there, but at the very least if you wanted to prevent the total cell from being a huge if statement you could try keeping the intermediate results of the if statements in separate cells for each level. For ex,
Level1_A in E1: =MIN(B1, 1000)
Level1_B in F1: =IF(B1 < 1000, MIN(B2, 1000 - B1), 0)

Then call them in the final total column
(E1*F1....) + ...
